# Learning CSS div placement , positioning

Tags: css

i am learning CSS, i am trying to place the div with red background just below the body, i can't seem to make it fit to the body, whenever i adjust the width it doesn't align with the body,when i tried to place it center and 100% width, it occupies 100% of the width of the page it does not align with the white background area, whenever i do 80% it does align left and does not align with the white background area. Please point me to the right direction. I'm stuck :(

the code i have so far is here: http://pastebin.com/VPMgbzQ2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference, I suggest posting a fiddle link. I've saved you the time. http://jsfiddle.net/mmAaQ/

Comment: I am having a really hard time trying to understand what you're trying to do. It seems like you need to redo a lot of what you have. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to put the all right's reserve*red background at the bottom of the page align with the body's width, i'm sorry but the all right's reserve is still in the same position :S

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning on it? Just leave everything as block level elements with static positioning, and it should work fine.

Comment: In general, avoid absolute positioning.  There's almost always a better and more reliable way to accomplish a layout.  Try a few CSS tutorials - Google will supply you with plenty - and you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your footer `div` out of the tabs `div` and no need of `position: absolute` on it. Make following changes:

```
#footer
{
        margin-top:80%;
        height: 20px;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        background:#C00; 
}
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmAaQ/1/).

Also it seems that you are trying to make responsive design but let me tell you that the way you are proceeding is not the right one for it. You may read [Responsive Design By Ethan Marcotte](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) for learning it.

**EDIT**

Make following changes:

1. Give `height: 400px;` or as required to table `div`.
2. Make your footer `div` out of the table `div`.
3. Either remove `margin-top` or change it to 5% or 10% as required in footer `div`.
4. Add `min-height: 100%;` to `.tabs`.

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9uRx/6/).

Comment: i'm lost i'm sorry :( i've been trying to thinker on the height and margin, i can't find a way to remove the space between the body and all rights reserve, is there any way to remove it out?
screenshot of the space to remove pointed by blue arrow: http://s14.postimg.org/5v35t6mj5/zzzzzzzzzzzzzz.png
here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/y9uRx/ Hope you can point me to the right direction :/

Comment: Editted again. Check Fiddle.

Comment: Kudos :) but how do you prevent the whole website from dislocating/collapsing whenever you resize the broswer to a smaller window?
here's a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/5g67o0783/
?Thanks :D

Comment: you can set a min-width on the body to prevent it from scaling down "too small".

Comment: Make a `div` inside body and give it a fixed `width` and `margin: 0px auto;` and then work only inside this `div`. Check out this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/E2brW/

Answer (score 0):

Try hardcoding the height value

```
#spaceheader {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue now. The parent element `<div class="tab">` is what's causing your issues. If I were you, I'd take the radio buttons out of the tab, make it not have a float:left on it, and this will probably fix things. You then need to remove the absolute positioning on your footer div.

Also, it looked like you put the footer div inside of the tab, when in actuality, it should be outside of all of the tabs, beneath them in the code.